# Save to access database at 8pm or specific time

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

i need to save to database at specific time at 8pm i cant seem to save it..

```
Public Sub updateDatabase(ByVal data As String) // update database using this function
    With txtIn //textbox 

            'Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("D:\POLI\SEM 5\PROJECT\Monitoring PH and Temperature\Monitoring PH and Temperature\PHTempdb.mdb")
            'Dim sql2 As String = String.Empty

            Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\POLI\SEM 5\PROJECT\Monitoring PH and Temperature\Monitoring PH and Temperature\PHTempdb.mdb") //database 

            'Dim dateTime.Now As String = Date 
            Dim date1 As Date = DateTime.Now

            Dim str As String = date1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            Dim insert As String = "INSERT INTO report (PHVALUE_TEMPERATURE, DATE_TIME) VALUES ('" & data & "', '" & DateTime.Now & "');"

            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
        conn.Open()

        If (DateTime.Now.Hour = 20 & DateTime.Now.Minute = 00) Then //save at 8 pm daily

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() // execute 
        End If

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        '.Clear()
        'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        ' End If
        '.Clear()
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles sp.DataReceived
    Dim str As String = sp.ReadExisting()
    Invoke(myDelegate, str)
    updateDatabase(str)


End Sub
```

Comment: That code won't work unless you call it at just the right time.  A better idea would be to use a `Timer`.  Determine exactly how many milliseconds there are until the time you want, set the `Interval` of the `Timer` to that number and then call its `Start` method.  The `Tick` event will be raised very close to the specified time.  If you don't want to do the saving on the UI thread the use a `Timers.Timer` instead, which will raise its `Elapsed` event on a secondary thread.

Comment: Would be a rather low chance of your code getting called at _exactly_ 8 o‘clock, IMO.

Comment: Look here it uses windows tasks scheduler: https://web.archive.org/web/20121018022007/http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2008/11/access-101-how-do-i-run-process.html

Comment: You can put it on infinite loop `While 1 = 1` and put that function to check the current time. But possible the best approach for those things is going with windows service  [MSDN - Creating a windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) . All advanced apps use services for those kinds of things

Answer (score 0):

If you can save your database programmatically normally by simply running a procedure, then you can [add a `Timer` Control to your form](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component) and then set it to run in the appropriate of **milliseconds** from now.

Given the scheduled datetime and the [current datetime](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-now-vbnet) you can use [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.datediff) to calculate the number of seconds from "now", and multiply by `1000` to get milliseconds.

You can find detailed instructions on using the Timer Control [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component) and [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/timer-vbnet).

---

### Notes

- At the beginning of the procedure called by the timer event, set the `Enabled` property to `False` to stop the procedure from running again. (Setting the interval to `0` does **not** cause the timer to stop.)
- Since the timer interval was set **relative to *current time***, it can't be "re-used" but if you want to automatically schedule the procedure again for the following day, you can simply recalculate the number of milliseconds and reset timer at the end of execution of your procedure.
- The maximum value for the `Interval` is 2,147,483,647 milliseconds so the farthest in the future you can set a schedule using this method is about **25 days**.